# Ajax and Facebook comments

Tags: ajax, facebook, plugins, comments, reload

I'm developing my own website for my projects. The Project Tab works with Ajax, and users can comment on each project. The problem is that when I use ajax to call a project page, those project comments do not load.

I've read everywhere that I need to parse this new code, but I don't know how. Can someone please explain me step by step how to do it?

PS: The comments work when I reload the page.

Comment: This has been discussed here lots of times before – http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xfbml+ajax

Answer (score 0):

After your ajax call, use this function: FB.XFBML.parse();